# Cannot open opencv processed image android

Tags: android, opencv

I have the following piece of code where I extract the image data to a `Mat` object and then draw a circle. Thereafter I try to put the processed data back into a `byte[]` array. The file is saved, but when I open it afterwards I get the message that it cannot be opened.

```
private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
    /**
     * The JPEG image
     */
    private final Image mImage;

    private final File mFile;

    ImageSaver(Image image, File file){
        mImage = image;
        mFile = file;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);

        Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bytes), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        Point pt = new Point(mat.width()/2, mat.height()/2);
        int radius = 40;
        Scalar color = new Scalar(256,0,0);
        Imgproc.circle(mat, pt, radius, color);
        int length = (int) (mat.total() * mat.elemSize());
        byte[] newBytes = new byte[length];
        mat.get(0,0,newBytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            output.write(newBytes);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if (output != null){
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As suggested by Micka, it is probably possible to use imwrite. But what if I want to show the processed image on the screen before capturing the image? Then I must copy the processed `bytes` to the `Image`?

I want to use the native camera instead since that seems to be faster and gives higher resolution.

Comment: use imwrite function to save as image file. If you want tosave raw data you'll have to use a custom reader to interpret the data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found an answer to my own question. First, it is indeed the simplest solution to use `imwrite` if saving the image is the only goal.

An alternative is to use

```
MatOfByte mByte = new MatOfByte();
Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpeg", mat, mByte);
...
output.write(mByte.toArray());
...
```